# Using a "not" operator before an ellipsis

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to make a function using a `!` logical operator before an ellipsis `...`.

Below is a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)

myfun <- function(data, ...) {
  filter(data, !(...))
}
```

The function does not work and throw the following error:

```
> myfun(iris, Sepal.Width < 4)
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'Sepal.Width' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `!(...)`.
```

How can I make it work?

Note that for my purpose, I have to negate the condition inside `myfun`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the `rlang` approach:

```
myfun <- function(data, ...) {
  x <- rlang::enquos(...)
  filter(data, !(!!!x))
}

myfun(iris, Sepal.Width < 4)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
2          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
3          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
4          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: That's a **lot** of   `!` .  For those of us who rarely use tidyverse, could you expand a bit on what that does?  I am guessing the first on converts to logical and the next inverts, but after that?

Comment: In this case `!!!` is the "big bang operator" which forces expression of the enquosured dots argument. See the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/tidyeval.pdf) for more.

Answer (score 2):

A better option might be to simply filter as usual, and then remove the filtered rows from the original dataset - e.g. using `anti_join()` as follows:

```
myfun2 <- function(data, ...) {

discard <- filter(data, ...)
dplyr::anti_join(data, discard, by = colnames(discard))

}
```

Comment: That works but @Ian Campbell's solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

myfun <- function(data, param, argument) {
  filter(data, data[[param]] != argument)
}

iris1 = as.data.table(iris)
myfun(iris, param = "Species", argument = "setosa")
```

Comment: Why add `data.table` as a dependency?

Comment: This would work in very specific situations. It is however much less flexible than using an ellipsis.

Comment: tidyverse does include data.table by default. No need to include data.table specifically. I agree, using ellipsis makes more sense in this situation.